# Validate date format in if loop condition using AWK

Tags: shell, csv, validation, date, awk

I have this piece of code

```
awk'{ 
  #some other code
  if(date -d data[i]){
    printf data[i]
    printf "valid\n"
  }else{
   printf "invalid\n"
  }
}sdata.csv
```

1. **sdata.csv** contains

   23/12/2018

   12/23/2018
2. **data[i]** contains date values from sdata.csv file.

I need to validate date format (**MM/DD/YYYY**) using **awk** but this code is printing **valid** for both date values from sdata.csv . Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

```
arobert@arobert-VirtualBox [16:07:15]
awk 'BEGIN{ret = system("date -d 23/12/2018 >/dev/null 2>&1"); print "return value=" ret}'                                                   
return value=1
arobert@arobert-VirtualBox [16:07:16]
[/home/arobert/sedTest] >
awk 'BEGIN{ret = system("date -d 12/23/2018 >/dev/null 2>&1"); print "return value=" ret}'                                                   
return value=0
```

call `date` command save its return code and then check that the rc is equal to 0 when the date format is correct or equal to 1 when it is not.

Your code becomes:

```
awk'{ 
  #some other code
  strCmd = "date -d"data[i]">/dev/null 2>&1"
  ret = system(str)
  if(ret == 0){
    printf data[i]
    printf "valid\n"
  }else{
   printf "invalid\n"
  }
}sdata.csv
```

Let me know if you need more support!

Comment: It's not fetching me the correct result. Its calculating all dates as VALID. Is it because of awk version? I have 3.1.7.

Comment: could you try to use the date command you are using outside of awk just to test if it's not your date command that causes the problem? thanks!

Comment: Ya it's working outside but not in awk bracket. Thanks.

Comment: I think It's because we are passing a variable in strCmd. I tried it with variable and it's fetching wrong result .

Answer (score 0):

You need proper match for the date format:

```
$ awk '/^(0[0-9]|1[012])\/([012][0-9]|3[01])/' sdata.csv
12/23/2018
```

Of course it won't recognize 11/12 vs 12/11.